# Multi color -Time series scatter plot in python

Tags: python, time-series, scatter-plot

I'm a newbie to python. I have time series data for which I need a scatter plot.
I basically want the normal and abnormal tags to have different colors. See below images of the data and plot:

### Actual data

### [image]

### Expected rearrangement in Data

[image]

---

### Expected Plot

[image]

---

I'll be very thankful for any leads in this!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot`'s [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter('#normal_TimestampColumn', '#normalColumn', facecolors='b')
plt.scatter('#abnormal_timestampColumn', '#abnormalColumn', facecolors='orange')
```

Comment: Thanks! But,I only have the data in "actual data" template. I need to rearrange the data with Normal and abnormal columns and then plot

Comment: @Unknown You need to edit your question then. What you are asking for now is a bit different from the actual question. You could take a look at `pandas` dataframe for the rearranging part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471241/python-replacing-scores-with-actual-valuetransposing

Comment: Any idea,how do I write it as a function? For multi color chart