# Python-Replacing scores with actual value(Transposing)

Tags: python, transpose

I have this data that looks like

```css
 Time            Pressure Normal/Abnormal
11/30/2011 22:50 74.3   0
11/30/2011 23:00 74.8   1
11/30/2011 23:10 77.7   1
11/30/2011 23:30 74.8   0
11/30/2011 13:00 80.9   0
```

```css
Desired Output:

Time             Normal Time             Abnormal
11/30/2011 22:50 74.3 11/30/2011 23:00 74.8
11/30/2011 23:30 74.8 11/30/2011 23:10 77.7
11/30/2011 13:00 80.9
```

---

I want to transpose the rows like mentioned in the "desired output".I  understand that I need to use something similar to melt and cast(used in R),but am unsure how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data above

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import itertools

text = u'Time \t          Pressure\tNormal/Abnormal\n11/30/2011 22:50\t74.3\t  0\n11/30/2011 23:00\t74.8\t  1\n11/30/2011 23:10\t77.7\t  1\n11/30/2011 23:30\t74.8\t  0\n11/30/2011 13:00\t80.9\t  0'

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(text))
normal = df.loc[df['Normal/Abnormal'] == 0].as_matrix()
abnormal = df.loc[df['Normal/Abnormal'] == 1].as_matrix()

columns = ["Time", "Normal", "Time", "Abnormal"]
out = []

for nr, ar in itertools.izip_longest(normal, abnormal, fillvalue=['', '']):
    # Concat rows horizontally (i.e. hstack)
    r = list(nr[:2]) + list(ar[:2])
    out.append(r)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=columns)

print df2.to_string(index=False)

''' Output
Time  Normal              Time Abnormal
11/30/2011 22:50    74.3  11/30/2011 23:00     74.8
11/30/2011 23:30    74.8  11/30/2011 23:10     77.7
11/30/2011 13:00    80.9
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

construct two data frames, 1 for normal & 1 for abnormal and then concat & edit column names

```
out = pd.concat([
  df[df['Normal/Abnormal'] == k].iloc[:, [0,1]].reset_index(drop=True)
  for k in [0, 1]], axis=1
)
out.columns = ['Time', 'Normal', 'Time', 'Abnormal']
out
               Time  Normal              Time  Abnormal
0  11/30/2011 22:50    74.3  11/30/2011 23:00      74.8
1  11/30/2011 23:30    74.8  11/30/2011 23:10      77.7
2  11/30/2011 13:00    80.9               NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for that! In the actual data,I have scores as 1's and 0's. I would need to create 2 columns and then fill the pressure value in those respective columns. those that have score 1 will have the pressure value against the time in Abnormal column. Hope I make the question clear now.

Comment: sorry, i think i got more confused after your comment.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do it?